# Backbone/Rails 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, routes

Hello so I am trying to rig up some JQuery in my Backbone/Rails app.

In my Backbone router I have the following code:

```
$.post(
    '/articles/force_update',
    {feed_url: "http://asciicasts.com/episodes.xml"},
    function(){
      console.log('is this Feedzirra thing on?');
     }
     // ,'json'
);
```

If I leave off the /force_update part I do not get any errors. But when I put it back in I get a 500(Internal Server Error) in my console.

Here is what I have in my routes.rb

```
routes.rb

  resources :articles do
    collection do
      post 'force_update'
    end
  end
```

The part that gets me is I am actually recreating an app I built a few months ago and I used the exact same code. It worked fine then but not now.

Any ideas?

Thank you

***Update***

The tail logs are giving me the following:

```
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)
```

and the server log is telling me something about a missing template. Here is the beginning part, there are too many lines to paste:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template articles/force_update, application/force_update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
```

Anybody knows what that means?

Hopefully somebody can help me navigate through this:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `force_update` action, it is clear that you are not calling `render` or `redirect`, so Rails by default looks for a file called `force_update.html.erb`. This can be fixed by calling

```
render 'my_file_name'
```

or

```
redirect 'a_redirect_action'
```

Comment: This is the line that gives it all away `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template articles/force_update`